# Discord.js why it shows me error message while trying to get list of bots guilds?

Tags: discord.js

I tried to use get list of bots guilds but it shows me an error.

**Input:**

```
bot.guilds.map(g=>g.name).join('\n')
```

**Output:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you try to console.log(bot.guilds) and post the response?

Comment: Can you also `console.log(bot)` and post the response?

Comment: ok it works and how to leave a specific guild using eval?

Comment: Use [`Guild.leave()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=leave)

Answer (score 0):

first you have to define it.

```
bot.guilds = new Map();
```

and instead of 
`bot.guilds.map()` you can use
`bot.guilds.set();`. I hope it works..